# imgur_client.search_gallery doesn't yield many images

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, imgur

I wonder how can I modify this code so that it will show more queries? Right now it only shows 59 queries that only one of them has more than 30 comments:

```
  9 imgur_client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret, access_token, refresh_token)
 10 
 11 search = imgur_client.gallery_search('cat', window='all')
 12 print(len(search))
 13 
 14 print(type(search[0]))
 15 print(dir(search[0]))
 16 print(type(search))
 17 
 18 print(search[0].id)
 19 print(random.choice(search).link)
 20 
 21 for i in range(0, len(search)):
 22     print(search[i].link)
 23     if search[i].comment_count > 10:
 24         count = 0
 25         for post in imgur_client.gallery_item_comments(search[i].id, sort='best'):
 26             if count <= 30:
 27                 print post.comment
 28             count += 1
```

I have:

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/imgur$ python download.py 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
59
<class 'imgurpython.imgur.models.gallery_album.GalleryAlbum'>
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'account_id', 'account_url', 'comment_count', 'cover', 'cover_height', 'cover_width', 'datetime', 'description', 'downs', 'favorite', 'id', 'images_count', 'in_gallery', 'is_ad', 'is_album', 'layout', 'link', 'nsfw', 'points', 'privacy', 'score', 'section', 'title', 'topic', 'topic_id', 'ups', 'views', 'vote']
<type 'list'>
E7WWf
http://imgur.com/a/zx507
http://imgur.com/a/E7WWf
http://imgur.com/a/dakxH
http://imgur.com/a/wfmk4
http://imgur.com/a/U7f2S
http://imgur.com/a/fu7q6
http://imgur.com/a/wwIqU
http://imgur.com/a/kTwtF
http://imgur.com/a/QqbSl
http://imgur.com/a/cxviy
http://imgur.com/a/g0cXi
http://i.imgur.com/9zg6EZd.gif
http://imgur.com/a/vYZXX
http://imgur.com/a/QFZqB
http://imgur.com/a/5JV8O
http://imgur.com/a/xuR32
http://i.imgur.com/9Ut5Nci.jpg
http://imgur.com/a/KMmmK
http://imgur.com/a/8K8Cf
http://imgur.com/a/RHndJ
http://imgur.com/a/3zvW1
http://imgur.com/a/tYWcR
http://imgur.com/a/YBYcZ
http://imgur.com/a/rb40b
http://imgur.com/a/fpBKP
http://imgur.com/a/hYmda
http://i.imgur.com/88TELvj.gif
http://imgur.com/a/aHEGE
http://imgur.com/a/oODh0
http://i.imgur.com/lfEUPJR.jpg
http://imgur.com/a/u0Cb4
http://imgur.com/a/EQjnP
http://imgur.com/a/5KQLb
http://i.imgur.com/laMSJU6.png
http://imgur.com/a/zx507
http://imgur.com/a/ryf0H
http://i.imgur.com/Z7s62fp.jpg
http://imgur.com/a/zbaw1
http://imgur.com/a/7oZMM
http://i.imgur.com/zWohUjv.gif
http://imgur.com/a/7jk4t
http://imgur.com/a/9hGyR
http://imgur.com/a/Y0clC
http://imgur.com/a/h7D2Z
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
vet, now.
whats in the jar on the table?
Image last seen 3.0 years before at https://imgur.com/gallery/phREVH7 Title similarity: ★★★★★ (5/5)
Get her chip checked, please.  She looks healthy enouh that she's probably a pet
Definitely go to a vet. They served our country and love cats.
make sure she's not a domesticated outdoorsy cat.I have a lot of kitties running around where I live, and they are owned. Might be somebodys
You reposting piece of shit OP, go kill yourself
Looks like she's got some eye smegma going on,if you really want to keep her,wouldn't her to get her checked out.
Do you want cats? Cause that's how you get cats!
I wanted to talk about their jar of weed and records in the back but it's a repost.
You have been chosen! Enjoy your new furry overlord.
Are you in Brisbane?
For some reason I read, "I have a cow now" and was highly confused based from the picture.
Nope, the cat has *you* now.
You've been chosen.
You've been adopted!
Quit smokin catnip ffs
That looks almost exactly like my cat. His name is Morty.
http://imgur.com/a/jVsoK
http://imgur.com/a/kWqPt
http://imgur.com/a/ZEUBu
http://imgur.com/a/gBPFO
http://imgur.com/a/C0Js1
http://i.imgur.com/EA3pyJt.png
http://imgur.com/a/WaM3t
http://imgur.com/a/berUE
http://imgur.com/a/xfiyU
http://i.imgur.com/M4q7QnK.jpg
http://imgur.com/a/wg0Re
http://imgur.com/a/DIY8b
http://i.imgur.com/mJcXmWe.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/R0a9oI9h.gif
http://imgur.com/a/2qWZ8
http://i.imgur.com/LwD4UAY.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `page=` parameter to gallery_search to get the next page of results and iterate over them that way.

Comment: I don't want to use page argument because it just grabs the data from one page. I need to get all the data not page by page

Comment: search = imgur_client.gallery_search('cat', window='all', sort='time', page=100) gives only the stuff on the 100 page and that's a limitation. I was looking for most popular imgurs over time

Comment: also please have a look at this issue: https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython/issues/74 I created a for loop and now I get this error at random iterations

Comment: or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099046/raise-imgurclienterrorjson-decoding-of-response-failed-imgurpython-helpers

Comment: "I need to get all the data". You're not going to find some message which returns the thousands or hundreds of thousands of images that match your search. I'm sorry, but you have to iterate using `page=` in a for loop.